# Changing main image in a gallery of an basic webpage without javascript and refresh

Tags: php, html, css, web

I have been looking for a way to change a main image without using javascript AND not refreshing the page. By reading the title I am sure you will be thinking 'this chap is an idiot an minimum of refreshing the page is required, however, I have seen on ASOS e.g. http://www.asos.com/ASOS/ASOS-2-In-1-Fishtail-Parka/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=3132737&cid=12931&sh=0&pge=0&pgesize=36&sort=-1&clr=Black#ctl00_ContentMainPage_mainImage2

they have managed to achieve this by what appears to be to load the main images as well as the thumbnail, then hide the unused main images and then once it is clicked to show the main image.

I have no idea how they are doing this as I am definitely not an expert but I hope someone can help and tell me how I can achieve the same functionality. I guess it is some CSS stuff but not a clue really.

A JSFiddle with explanation would be the worlds most ideal answer

Thanks

Comment: You can do that using CSS transitions and the `:target` or `:checked` selectors.  However, that site does it using Javascript.

Comment: I turned javascript off and used the site and it was working

Comment: For that, they're using `:target` in CSS.

Comment: Topping going to read about it nowzies

Comment: Just google `slider without javascript` or `css3 slider` and you will find a lot of tutorials